# Change MySql value based on time that has past

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
user_id     post_streak   streak_date          streak       first_name  club_id
--------    -----------   ------------         ---------    ----------- --------
18941684    1             2015-05-05 15:36:18    3           user       1000
```

I want to change streak to 0 if it has been longer then 12 days.

current query:

```
select 
     first_name, streak, user_id from myTable 
where 
     club_id = 1000 
and 
     post_streak = 1 
and 
     streak_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 12 DAY) and now() 
order by streak desc;
```

Which doesn't show results older then 12 days.  I want to show all results but change "streak" to 0 if it has been longer the 12 days.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: try between dateadd(day,-12,now() ) and now()                                           sorry never mind this will probably get you the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET (streak)
VALUES (0)
WHERE streak_date < DATEADD(DAY, -12, NOW() );
SELECT first_name, streak, user_id from myTable 
WHERE
     club_id = 1000 
AND 
     post_streak = 1 
ORDER BY streak DESC;
```

First query will set all streak values to 0 for records that have streak_date of more than 12 days ago
Second query will get a list of all your records that have a club_id of 1000 and a post_streak of 1

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition in the `select`, rather than the `where`:

```
select first_name,
       (case when streak_date between date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 12 DAY) and now()  
             then streak
             else 0
        end) as streak,
       user_id from myTable 
where club_id = 1000 
order by streak desc;
```

I'm not sure if the `post_streak` condition is needed in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8bbd/6

```
select 
     user_id,
     first_name, 
     streak_date,
     IF(streak_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 12 DAY) and now(),streak,0) 
from myTable 
where 
     club_id = 1000 
and 
     post_streak = 1 
order by streak desc;
```